# Input(shape=(6,7)) expects 3 dimensions on model.predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, multidimensional-array, keras, valueerror

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: 
expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (6, 7)
```

```
_____________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==============================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 6, 7)         0
```

```
    out1, out2 = model.predict(board)
```

```
    inputs = Input(shape=(6,7))
    inputs_reshape = Reshape((6,7,1))(inputs) # channels, batch_size, rows, cols
    net = Conv2D(4, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', 
            padding='same', data_format='channels_last')(inputs_reshape)
    net = Flatten()(net)
    pi = Dense(7, activation='softmax', name='pi')(net) 
    v = Dense(1, activation='tanh', name='v')(net)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[v, pi])
```

from the keras.io docs, it says that the `shape` dimensions for `Input()` does not include the batch size, and that `mdoel.predict()` sets `batch_size=32` by default.

if `model.predict(data)` expects `data.shape` to be `(batches, 6,7)`, what's the difference between `model.predict(data, batch_size=1` and `model.predict_on_batch(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `batch_shape` of your model is `(None, 6, 7)`, three dimensions. The first value `None` is the batch size (which is free to be any value).

So it's expecting your data to have 3 dimensions, as the `batch_shape` determines.

Comment: but keras ``mode.predict()`` is supposed to fill the batch size automatically. that's why it has a ``batch_size parameter``, right?

Comment: if ``model.predict(data)`` expects ``data.shape`` to be ``(batches, 6,7)``, what's the difference between ``model.predict(data, batch_size=1`` and ``model.predict_on_batch(data)``

Comment: The first will predict many times with batch size = 1, the second will predict one time with the entire data.